# How to reduce anxiety about travelling using airplanes?

Tags: aircraft, airbus

I am new to aviation and flying.
I have a one hour trip tomorrow on airbus a320 that is making me anxious and sleepless.

How can I manage the fear and is it safe or just like the bad stuff we hear on news?

Comment: What are you anxious about? Discomfort? Intrusive security searches? Missing your flight because of unfamiliarity with airports? There are different ways to deal with these than with fear of the actual flight and what might go wrong in the worst case, which is statistically irrational (not that it's much help knowing that to people with fears).

Comment: @ChrisH thanks. But I did not understand your last sentence.

Comment: By bad stuff, do you mean accidents or [flight-shaming](https://www.bbc.com/worklife/article/20190718-flygskam)?

Comment: @Am90 I was thinking of worries about accidents, without wanting to use the word, or feeling the need to, as my aim was to find out what you're worried about, rather than to put ideas in your head. Worries about missing the flight can be addressed with planning, airport maps, and plenty of time in hand; there are ways to make security much smoother (though there are  random checks)

Comment: I am thinking of crashes Chris.

Answer (score 0):

*Travel fever* is common and doesn't have to do with the flight itself but could be the trip, the destination, being away from home etc.

When arriving at the airport, take your time and check things out. The first thing I do after passing airport security is to find my gate. That way I know how much time it will take for me to get to the gate from whereever I'd be when the gate opens.

Check if the airport has an app where you can track the status of the flight. You should be able to receive notifications for when the gate opens so that you don't miss it. However, don't rely on the notifications! Show up at the gate at least 40 minutes before departure time as many gates close 30 minutes before.

If you're a drinker I'd suggest getting a couple of beers after security (not too much) and on the plane. Upgrading to Economy Plus could be more economical if this is what you want to do as drinks are usually free both at the airport and in-flight. There are also the options of getting a day pass at an airport lounge where drinks are included.

If you have a window seat you can use advanced GPS apps for your phone to track the planes speed and altitude. I find this very enjoyable.

Prepare your phone with some offline music and series, and get good headphones. I prefer in-ear but overear are also fine. You want them to cancel out as much noise as possible - the engine noise can be unbearable for some.

Comment: Thanks Mikael. What scares me the most if the plane accidents and crashes